# Angular 4 doesn't work with IE 9

Tags: angular

I'm trying to launch angular app (ng new "appname") with IE 9
but it only works when I reload page with open IE9 dev tools window

I added (uncomment) all necessary polyfills in polyfills.ts

Here is the [video](https://vimeo.com/240372636)

Angular 4.2.4

**Updated**
Thank you, Martin

Finally get it working with console-polyfill and with zonejs

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="zone.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using `console` in your code (the problem is in `main.bundle.js`). If you want to use it and support IE9 at the same time, you will need to add another polyfill for it.

You could use this one probably:

https://github.com/paulmillr/console-polyfill

I tried to create new app and build it, there is one usage of `console` and it is in the `src/main.ts` file, you could also check if there is `console` supported and use it only in that case:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => 'console' in window ? console.log(err) : null);
```